# Is it possible to open the app clip window from TestFlight?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, app-store-connect, apple-appclips

I ran into a problem.
I created an app clip, added it to the well-know site, and added the associated domain to the app.
Uploaded the assembly to testflight.
In the metadata, in the domain check, the status is confirmed.

I upload the app clip to the device.
I go to the settings, the developer and add the local experience app clip.
I'm trying to scan the QR code, but instead of the appclip, the safari url opens.

I decided to try installing the app clip from xcode, and perform all the same actions, and lo and behold, the app clip window opens.

What could be the reason why the local build works and the build from testflight does not?

The documentation from Apple does not say anything about this at all.

It seems to me that the assembly from testflight is not cached on the device and therefore it is impossible to open it through a qr code